# Reload controller or ng-include

Tags: angularjs, mean

I'm doing a carousel which draws its components database, The main problem is that it works only once.
Here I leave codes:
controlller:

```
'use strict';

// Carruselps controller
angular.module('carruselps').controller('CarruselpsController', ['$scope',    '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Carruselps',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Carruselps) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;


// Find a list of Carruselps
        $scope.find = function() {
            $scope.carruselps = Carruselps.query();
        };

    }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<section data-ng-controller="CarruselpsController" data-ng-init="find()">
     <carousel interval="5000">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in carruselps" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.imagen}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>{{slide.titulo}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.subtitulo}}</p>
          <a class="btn btn-default"  href="{{slide.boton}}">Ver más</a>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
</section>
```

and the front element:

```
<div ng-include="'modules/carruselps/views/carruselp.client.view.html'" id="c1"></div>
```

Comment: really not enough given to troubleshoot from since problem likely relates to directives that aren't shown. Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: That's all the code I used for the carousel. I have no inserted directive or something like that

Comment: well that `carousel` directive doesn't work just by throwing a tag in the html

Comment: I'm sorry .
I should say that if several things for granted. my mistake. I am using meanjs.